# using datetime.add(timespan) with linq but does not work

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```cs
var newStatusSummary = await(from q in db.QrCode where q.Status == 0 && **q.CreatedDate.Add(offset) * *>=start && **q.CreatedDate.Add(offset) * *<=end
group q by q.CreatedDate.Date into summary
select new {
    Date = summary.Key,
    Total = summary.Count()
}).ToListAsync();
```

Created date = {1/10/2019 12:00:00 AM}

Offset = {08:00:00}

But I cannot get the newStatusSummary. 
How Can I work around this?

Comment: Is this something like Entity Framework?

Comment: is async/await must be required in this part?

Comment: @Arphile That doesn't seem likely to make a difference.

Comment: you need to use `SqlFunctions` class for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

If this is linq to entity framework, replace `DateTime.Add()` with `DateTime.DateAdd()`:

```
var newStatusSummary = await (from q in db.QrCode where q.Status == 0
               && **q.CreatedDate.DateAdd(offset)** >= start
               && **q.CreatedDate.DateAdd(offset)** <= end
               group q by q.CreatedDate.Date into summary
               select new
               {
                  Date = summary.Key,
                  Total = summary.Count()
               }).ToListAsync();
```

Add the using statement `using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;`

**Edit**

Sorry, I did not notice that this was entity framework core. In that case, look at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1

I think you should be able to use the `DateDiffDay` method to compare dates.

Comment: `SqlFunctions.DateAdd` is not an extension method. But also, the question is probably about EF core.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the question is probably about EF core. And I had try to use SqlFunctions.DateAdd but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that, see my edit - I think EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions.DateDiffDay might help

Answer (score 0):

Please use [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.dateadd?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_SqlServer_SqlFunctions_DateAdd_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Double__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__) instead of Add. The difference is  Add - runtime function that works with runtime objects in .Net

DateAdd is special function that maps to Database function. And your request will mapped to SQL request with calling of [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) method.

If you use Add method. You should fetch data and convert it to objects before calling of Add method. (But it's bad idea. If threre are a lot of rows in DB it will failed)